# Where is certificate saved when adding to cert store in Linux

Tags: c#, .net-core, x509certificate2

Using .Net Core 2.1, Linux

```
var store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
storeRoot.Add(cert);
storeRoot.Close();
```

1. Where does the actual certificate get saved in the file system please? I have checked in "/etc/ssl/certs" but cannot identify my cert and so I am not sure if it's stored in there!
2. Is it possible to create an in-memory store? If so, how? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) This is considered a detail of the platform, and you shouldn't ever depend on it, and it's subject to change at any time. (But it's easily findable as ~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/x509stores/root in current versions).  Adding or modifying files in this directory (or any of the directories under ~/.dotnet/corefx/cryptography/) can break the product.

2) `X509Certificate2Collection`?  An "in-memory store" is either just a collection, or you're doing something with interop.  X509Store on Linux doesn't have a native representation, so there's no interop possibility.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Ref. answer #2,  I don't want to add certs permanently to the trusted root store, is it possible to load an X509Certificate2Collection and extend the real system cert store whilst my service is running? I.e. when serviced is downed, the temp store is removed. FYI, I'm trying to add intermediate and root cert so that my web app service's sends out intermediate ca. At the moment it only sends the leaf unless I install these CA certs but I only want them to be in the store for the length of the service.

Comment: @Rollhard No. There's a related feature request (https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/16364) but it's not implemented yet.  Your best bet would be to make an account for just that service, add the trust (using the X509Store.Add method) and let that service account always trust it.